# Rowcolor, Multicolumn, and Tabu

Tags: multicolumn, tabu, rowcolor

Ok, I want to create an environment that prepares my table in such a way that I have consistent results.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{colortbl} %make alternating row colours

\usepackage{tabu} % \rowfont

\usepackage{multirow} % for multirow and multicol
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{hhline} %to make hlines over a certain number of columns

\usepackage{array} % adds more features on how tables are used
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}} %left-align with specific size
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}%centre-align with specific size
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\rowcolors{2}{blue!15}{white}
\arrayrulecolor{blue}
\providecommand{\theader}{\rowfont{\color{white}}\rowcolor{blue}}

\newenvironment{myTable}[4][htbp]
{
    \begin{table}[#1]
        \begin{center}
            \caption{#4}\label{#3}

            \begin{tabu}{#2}
                \hline
            }{ 
            \end{tabu}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{myTable}[htb]{*{4}{c |}|*{2}{C{1.5cm} |}| C{3cm}}%
    {tbl:label}%
    {Caption Text}
    \theader$a$ & $b$ & $c$ & $d$ & $(a\land b)$ & $(c\land d)$ & $(a\land b)\lor(c\land d)$\\\hline
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    \multicolumn{4}{@{}c@{}}{\upbracefill} & \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\upbracefill} & \upbracefill\\
\end{myTable}
\end{document}
```

I create an environment *myTable* that contains a table and **tabu** environment.
However, whenever I use **\multicolumn** together with **\rowcolor**. 
I get the following compiler error:

> ! Emergency stop.
>   \multispan ->\omit 
>                     @multispan 
>   l.46 \end{myTable}

I had the same within a tabular environment and it worked fine. 
When I remove the multicolumn commands, it works fine.
When I remove the rowcolor command, it works fine.

I can work around it by placing a \cellcolor{white} in each multicolumn command. But that's not a solution.

Does anybody has any ideas on how to fix it???
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Tabu is currently unmaintained and causes some undesired behavior especially when convinced with color. I'd suggest switching to an alternative such as tabularx.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... It is not advisable to use the package `tabu`... Better switch over to normal `tabular` with `colortbl` support....

Comment: OK, [colortbl] is fine but I need tabu for the [\rowfont] command. (I need to set the font color for the entire row). Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 7):

Another option would be the new [tabularray](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package. The package allows you to completely separate the format from the content. It support cells spanning multiple columns and rows and coloring.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\NewColumnType{C}[1]{Q[c,wd=#1]}

\newenvironment{myTable}[4][htbp]
{
    \begin{table}[#1]
        \centering
        \caption{#4}\label{#3}          
        \begin{tblr}{
                colspec={#2},
                hline{1-Y}={blue},
                vline{1-Z}={1}{1-Y}{blue}, vline{5, 7}={2}{1-Y}{blue},
                row{even}={white}, row{odd}={blue!15},
                row{1}={bg=blue, fg=white, mode=math},
                row{Z}={white, rowsep=0pt},
            }
        }{ 
        \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{myTable}{*{4}{c}*{2}{C{1.5cm}}C{3cm}}%
    {tbl:label}%
    {Caption Text}
    a & b & c & d & (a\land b) & (c\land d) & (a\land b)\lor(c\land d) \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \SetCell[c=4]{c} \raisebox{2mm}{$\underbrace{\hspace{2cm}}$} & & & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} \raisebox{2mm}{$\underbrace{\hspace{4cm}}$} & & \raisebox{2mm}{$\underbrace{\hspace{3cm}}$} \\
\end{myTable}   
    
\end{document}
```

Which produces the output:

[image: tabular template]

You can specify the format using `row` and `column` parameters, e.q. I used the setting `mode=math` so you don't have to write `$$` every time in the first row.

Comment: this is a really good package!.. instructions are a bit happy.. but I worked it out :)